# "import org.andengine.util.adt.align.HorizontalAlign" throws error

Tags: import, andengine

When I try to import org.andengine.util.adt.align.HorizontalAlign it throws the error "The import org.andengine.util.adt.align cannot be resolved".
All the AndEngine GLES2 libraries are attached to my project. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by upgrading all libraries to GLES2-AnchorCenter.